# Run an NPM script inside every package in an NX project's library

Tags: npm, nx.dev

I'm using [NX](https://nx.dev/) to manage a React design system mono-repo. I want to create my components within an [NX Library](https://nx.dev/packages/react/generators/library#@nrwl/react:library) and am currently looking into creating a Node package which will run the CSS for each component through PostCSS to get it production ready.

I've tested my PostCSS Node package in isolation and I know it's doing what I need it to to the files, however I'm having trouble working out how to configure the NX repo to run an NPM script in each component's `package.json`. A component such as my Button component has a `package.json` like so:

```js
{
  "name": "css-components-button",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "tools-postcss 'lib/**/*.css' dist/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tools-postcss": "file:.yalc/tools-postcss"
  }
}
```

In the CSS Components Library the `project.json` file looks like this:

```js
{
  "name": "css-components",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/css-components/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": ["libs/css-components/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}"]
      }
    },
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/rollup:rollup",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/libs/css-components",
        "tsConfig": "libs/css-components/tsconfig.lib.json",
        "project": "libs/css-components/package.json",
        "entryFile": "libs/css-components/src/index.ts",
        "external": ["react/jsx-runtime"],
        "rollupConfig": "@nrwl/react/plugins/bundle-rollup",
        "compiler": "babel",
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "libs/css-components/README.md",
            "input": ".",
            "output": "."
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "libs/css-components/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true
      }
    },
    "prepack": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/workspace:run-script",
      "options": {
        "script": "prepack"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In particular I've added a `"prepack"` custom target which I'm trying to use to run a "prepack" NPM script in each component's `package.json`. Currently when I run `nx run css-components:prepack` in the Terminal I get `**error Command "prepack" not found.**`

Would really appreciate some help with this. Any ideas?

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: My solution was to stop using NX and use Yarn Workspaces instead. It took me a couple of days to configure all the tooling but I'm using Lerna to do this part of it now. You could potentially use Lerna to run the scripts in your NX repo? Bit of a workaround but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple packages on your monorepo and all or some of the packages have a script (let's say lint). For every package the scripts will be something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ./src --report-unused-disable-directives"
}
```

now in the main package.json you will have:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "nx run-many -t lint"
}
```

It's that simple, unfortunately, this basic use case is not presented in the docs and they provide something that is overcomplicated.